# How to programmatically close ng-bootstrap modal?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I've got a modal:

```
<template #warningModal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Warning</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      The numbers you have entered result in negative expenses.  We will treat this as $0.00.  Do you want to continue?
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">No</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="submit()">Yes</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Whenever I click yes, I want it to call a function and close itself.
In my controller, I have `@ViewChild('warningModal') warning;` and in `submit()`, I have `this.warning.close();`, but I get `this.warning.close is not a function` whenever I click Yes.

How do I get this to work the way I want it to?

Comment: is it ng-bootstrap or ng2-bootstrap?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/ (as indicated in your question) things are extremely simple - you can just open a modal and either close it from a template (as in your code) *or* programmatically (by calling `close()` method on the returned Object of type `NgbModalRef`).

Here is a minimal example showing this in action:  http://plnkr.co/edit/r7watmQuyaUQ8onY17Z1?p=preview

You might be either confusing different libraries or maybe there is sth more to your question but it is hard to say more based just on the info provided.

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly how I solved it.  I just forgot to come back and edit.  Your project is amazing, btw.

Comment: plunker doesn't work but your solution is work for me,

Answer (score 102):

To expound upon pkozlowski.opensource's response, the way I actually got the reference to the NgbModalRef class was by modifying what is in his plunker on the this.modalService.open as follows:

```
this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(content);
this.modalReference.result.then((result) => {
  this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
}, (reason) => {
  this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
});
```

Then I was able to call:

```
this.modalReference.close();
```

Which worked like a charm.  Oh, and don't forget to put define modalReference at the top of the class:

```
modalReference: any;
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Don't forget to import NgbModalRef!

Comment: you don't actually need to import it if you define `modalReference` like he did

Comment: you can optionally pass argument to close, eg, `this.modalReference.close("submitted");`

Answer (score 18):

Unlike TBrenner i couldn't' just use `modalReference: any;`

I run with:

```
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    with angular 5
```

I had to import in my app.module.ts

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

and of course add it to the providers:

```
providers[ NgbModal]
```

once it's done here is the code from the modal component:

```
 import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'; 
 import { ModalDismissReasons, NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng 
 bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class MyClass {
modalReference: NgbModalRef;

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal)
open(content) {
this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(content);
this.modalReference.result.then((result) => {
  this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
}, (reason) => {
  this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
});
}

private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
  return 'by pressing ESC';
} else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
  return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
} else {
  return `with: ${reason}`;
}
}

JoinAndClose() {
this.modalReference.close();
}
```

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io should add some information about the reference importance.. I struggled a little bit to understand I needed to create a reference to access the ".close()" method. Thanks you all, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 15):

You can simply close the modal by below way.

First when we open the Modal

```
this.modalService.open(content, { size: "lg" }).result.then(
      result => {
        this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
      },
      reason => {
        this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
      }
```

After That in TS For closing use this

```
 this.modalService.dismissAll();
```

Comment: this.modalService.dismissAll(); this case work for me! Thank you buddy

Comment: This is fine if indeed you want to close all open modals but not if you want to keep one open.

Comment: Thanks!  This finally did it for me.

Answer (score 7):

To open the modal

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

modalReference = null;     

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {

   }

openVerticallyCentered(content) {
    this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true });
  }
```

to close the modal using the reference, like Amit said

```
this.modalReference.close();
```

source:https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: Adding to that, the model reference can be set to type: `NgbModalRef`.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is:
Import NgbModalRef

```
import { NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Set type

```
modalRef: NgbModalRef;
```

Html:

```
<button (click)="openModal(myModal)"></button>
```

Component:

```
 openModal(content: any) {
   this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content);
 }
```

Then add this in a function where you want to call the close

```
this.modalRef.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `let-d` or `let-c` in `<template #warningModal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">` as variables, both are functions. So, the simple way to do it is:  pass in `c` or `d` into submit as argument like this `(click)="submit(c)"` or `(click)="submit(d)"` and then in the function just call `submit(c){ c('close modal'); }`. Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done with `@ViewChild('warningModal') warning` is get the [`TemplateRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/TemplateRef-class.html) you used as in your modal, not the actual `NgbModalRef`.

It depends how you open up your modal, if you open it programmatically you should receive the `NgbModalRef` object which you could call `.close` on.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion: the modal is responsible for closing itself and not the caller of the modal.

A modal can simply access the `NgbActiveModal` class, through the injector, and close itself by either calling the close or dismiss function.

```
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class Modal {

    constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
    }

    public submit() {
        this.activeModal.close(/* your result */);
    }

    public close() {
        this.activeModal.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a hacky way to do this from a centralized app component level

```
this._platformLocation.onPopState(() => {
        document.getElementsByClassName('modal-header')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();
    });
```

this should be placed inside the constructor in app.component.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `let-c="close"` into the `saveChanges()` as parameter like below

```
<button *ngIf="!showloader" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveChanges(c)">
```

Use it under component method like below and modal will be closed

```
saveChanges(close) {
  // Additional implementation code here
  // .... & finally close the modal
  close('Close Clicked');
}
```