# Jquery button click event not fired if button is on ng-bootstrap Modal popup in Angular5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular5, ng-bootstrap

In my application, I have used modal popup of jquery.I have developed the ng-bootstrap modal pop using [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) link as reference.

I have a js file where button click event is handled.
If I place my button in app.component.html, the jquery event is fired when button is clicked. But if I put the same button on modal popup, the event is not fired.

I want the event to be fired when I click the button on modal popup as well.

Comment: Could you please edit your post adding a piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you are using this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on("click","#item", function(){
     console.log(1);
   }
 }
```

`$('#item').click()` will not work here.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Could you also tell me how to close/hide the popup in this event?

Comment: without seeing your code i am afraid i can't give details on closing/hiding . may be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44269431/7477198