# How to close ngboostrap model while submiting the form?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

How to close ngbootstrap model along with form submission inside the model window. I am using angular 6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programatically close ng-bootstrap modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382319/how-to-programatically-close-ng-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 0):

In the submit button, **call** the close function

```
<button  (click)="d('Cross click')">Submit</button>
```

Or **bind** it with submit event

```
import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

....

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

submit() {
   const modalRef = this.modalService.close(NgbdModalContent);
}
```