# How to hide bootstrap modal in angular

Tags: angular, angular5, bootstrap-modal, angular6

I am using bootstrap modal but when I hide it from code-behind it shows the error below.

I am using angular6.

**Code**

```
<div #exampleModal class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">

  @ViewChild('exampleModal') public exampleModal: ElementRef;

 this.exampleModal.hide();
```

**Error message**

> ERROR TypeError: this.exampleModal.hide is not a function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programatically close ng-bootstrap modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382319/how-to-programatically-close-ng-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 9):

You can add close button HTML in your modal dialog and add template variable `#closebutton`

In ts code, you call `this.closebutton.nativeElement.click();` to close modal dialog.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Close</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" #closebutton class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Content here</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="closeModal"  (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
         </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

TS

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('closebutton') closebutton;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  public ngOnInit() {

  }

  public onSave() {
    this.closebutton.nativeElement.click();
  }
}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-close-bootstrap-modal?file=src/app/app.component.html

Update:

I have another solution without trick on close button.

First step you need install `jquery` and `bootstrap` by `npm` command.

Second you need add `declare var $ : any;` in component

And use can use $('#myModal').modal('hide'); on onSave() method

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-model-bootstrap-close?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: After lot of search, found this easiest solution which is explained in detail how to do it. Thanks. You rock.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" #myModal>
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Content here</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="closeModal"  (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
         </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('myModal', { static: false }) myModal: ModalDirective;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  public ngOnInit() {

  }

  public onSave() {
    this.myModal.hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to S/O - and thank you for actively contributing! :) Please consider expanding on your answer. It's helpful to provide context around an answer, instead of only code.

[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is well worth reading!

Comment: please explain why your solution works. The question itself is ambiguous, so you should ask questions in comment section to clarify the question rather than jumping to write an answer.

Comment: Hi all. I add @ViewChild as ModalDirective instead of ElementRef. So you can use show and hide methods because that viewchild is a modal.

Comment: Hi, where does the MOdalDirective comes from?

Answer (score 0):

I have a another option for this which is very easy and works for me.

E.x: This is your model code in HTML file.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeModel">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- Do your stuff -->
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>


  </div>
</div>
```

Now in your .ts file where you want to close modal just use `jquery` for that.

**Note: You need to install jquery for that and need to import in file.**

Now click on `close` button by `jquery.`

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#closeModel").click();  // That's it... Model will close. 
});
```

Comment: @Maddy Can you please update your status on answer/s ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use ngx-bootstrap modal for controlling modal from Code. https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals