# Hide Bootstrap Dialog in Angular 6 from Component

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to hide bootstrap dialog from a component with no luck.
My Dialog code is as below:

```
<div class="modal fade"  id="loading_video_upload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="loading_video_upload_label"
     aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <img src="/assets/gif/gear_loading.gif"/>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" #loading_video_upload_btn id="hidebutton" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="loading_video_upload">Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Component Code is as below:

```
...
@ViewChild('video_upload_success_btn')
videoUploadSuccessDialogBtn: ElementRef;

some-apimethod() {
  this.loadingDialog.nativeElement.click();
}
...
```

Please help me suggest where is not working.

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Comment: with @viewchild you are trying to access an angular component which does not  exist, try using native api which is not recommended but will work document.querySelector('#id_of_button')  for more info try this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: did you try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/56810262/4964569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#loading_video_upload').modal('hide');`

Install jquery and bootstrap by npm command.

Declare var $ : any; in component

Use can use `$('#loading_video_upload').modal('hide');` on some-apimethod() method

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-model-bootstrap-close