# Angular Bootstrap how can I close the modal?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I open my modal with this

```
(click)="openVerticallyCentered(content)"

import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

  openVerticallyCentered(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content);
  }

login(){

        this.authService.signinUser(this.userLogin.email, this.userLogin.password).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.toastr.success('Login Success .!!');
            this.activeModal.close();  // <-- calling .close() method when user login successfully but its not close 
        })

}
```

Which is working fine. But I need to close it by button. It's closing from html like this `(click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')"`  But I need to close it from .ts file.

I try with `this.modalService.close();` But it says close is not a type of modelService. Any solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically close ng-bootstrap modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382319/how-to-programmatically-close-ng-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 0):

You could find an example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-service?file=app%2Fmy-modal.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of **[How to programmatically close ng-bootstrap modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382319/how-to-programmatically-close-ng-bootstrap-modal)**

***Quick answer:***
You need to retrieve the modal instance then call the `close()` method on active modal (or any targeted modal) in the constructor by calling `NgbActiveModal`.

Example:

```
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...

export class LessonModalComponent {
...
  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  closeCustom() {
    console.log('close active modal');
    this.activeModal.close();  // <-- calling .close() method
  }
}
```

Here's a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-modal-gsw2es)
(check the "Close custom" button in any modal)

Comment: Thanks but dont know why its not working. Its closing by button. But not from function I need to do when user login in app .

Comment: Are you importing `NgbActiveModal` in your constructor like this: `constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }` as in my example?

Comment: can you please provide an example on Stackblitz please? It's hard to help you without a similar-case reproduction.