# Angular NgbModal, how to correctly close a modal window?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal, ng-modal

I am working on an Angular application using **NgbModal** to handle modal. I have some doubts about how properly close a modal implemented with this component (untill now I always used PrimeNg instead **ng-bootstrap**).

Basically I have done in this way (and it seems to works fine): into my TypeScript code I have something like this:

```
async post(): Promise<void> {
    this.submitted.next(true);
    try {
      await this.setAddress();
      this.modalService.dismissAll();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Storage upload error', e);
      this.submitted.next(false);
    }
}
```

Basically this method is called when a post is submitted. The **setAddress()** method save on the database (calling another service method) the form values. Then the modal was closed. It seems to works fine but I have the following doubt:

As you can see in order to close my modal I am using this **dismissAll()** method. Checking on the documentation: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api

It also indicates a **close()** method that I can not use on my code. Trying:

```
this.modalService.close();
```

the IDE says to me:

> Property 'close' does not exist on type 'NgbModal'.ts(2339)

Why in the official documentation I have this method but not in my code? The first used method (**dismissAll()**) is it correct? It is working but I have some doubts related to this "All" into the method name. Why "All"? it let me think that it is closing all the modals and not only a single one (in my use case in my page there is only a single modal so it is indifferent but I am not sure that I am implementing the correct logic to close my modal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're probably looking for the `close` method of [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbActiveModal) class. You need to inject the `NgbActiveModal` into your component instead of the `NgbModal` service.

I use the `close` method to gracefully close the modal. You could use the `dismiss` method when you want to return an error to the opener and `dismissAll` when there is more than one active moda instance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set reference of your opened modal

Like

```
this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(modalComponent);
```

And then for closing

```
this.modalReference.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `let-c="close"` into the `saveChanges()` as parameter like below

```
<button *ngIf="!showloader" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveChanges(c)">
```

Use it under component method like below and modal will be closed

```
saveChanges(close) {
  // Additional implementation code here
  // .... & finally close the modal
  close('Close Clicked');
}
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382319/how-to-programmatically-close-ng-bootstrap-modal)